# Weird bit manipulation in Python

Tags: python-2.7, bit-manipulation

Following are results of running the `bin` builtin function on the Python 2.7.2 interpreter:

```
   bin(5)
=> '0b101'
   bin(-5)
=> '-0b101'
   bin(5&-5)
=> '0b1'
```

With infinite bits and 2's complement:

`+5 = 0000...0101
-5 = 1111...1101`

Then why is `5&-5 = 0000...1`?

Shouldn't it be `0000...101`? What's the explanation for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You did your two's complement wrong. It would actually be: `1111...1011`

So `...1011 & ...0101` = 1.

Answer (score 2):

Actually 2's complement of -5 is `111.....1011`
now if you bit wise AND these two

```
  000...0101
& 111...1011
  ----------
  000...0001
```